# How do I create a Line Graph on App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this app script code that first deletes any existing graphs then I want it to put the x-axis as xRange and the series as yValues (To find my ranges, I used some other functions but they work correctly and get my wanted ranges) (I want the graph on the Graph spreadsheet)

```
function createLineGraph(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var attendance = ss.getSheetByName("Attendance");
  var graph = ss.getSheetByName("Graph");

  // Delete any existing line charts in the sheet
  var chts=graph.getCharts();
  for(var i=0;i<chts.length;i++){
    graph.removeChart(chts[i]);
  }


  var xRange = attendance.getRange("B1:"+getColumnLetter(findTotalAttendanceColumn(attendance)-1)+"1");
  var yValues = attendance.getRange("B"+findTotalAttendanceRow(attendance)+":"+getColumnLetter(findTotalAttendanceColumn(attendance)-1)+findTotalAttendanceRow(attendance));

}
```

For example: If the xRange was "hello","bye","idk" and the yValues were 2,8,5, then the line graph would look like this:
[image]

Could someone please tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: What is `findTotalAttendanceRow`? Is this AI generated code?

Comment: No, basically I'm using stuff with a google form and other app script functions that changes the rows a bunch so I created a function that looks for a row that contains a specific value

Comment: You just have to create embedded chart and pass the entire range (`A:B`, where A is x values and B is Y values) to it. There's no need  to accurately select the end row. See Embedded chart in the official docs.